# Whitespace at end of span affects absolute positioning of after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, dom, browser

In styling a component on my site, I found that adding whitespace to the end of my `span` that's inside an `h2` affects the absolute positioning of `span:after` in a weird way. The `after` element I use as a border. The border positions itself after the content without the whitespace, but positions itself over the content when there is whitespace. [You can see an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/3u2nr66h/).

**Any ideas on why this would render differently?**

html:

```
<h2>
<span>A test</span> <!-- the border appears 'after' the content -->
</h2>
<h2>
<span>A test </span> <!-- the border appears 'over' the content -->
</h2>
```

css:

```
h2 {
  position:relative;
  height:1.625em/1;
}
h2 span {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  1.625em/1 'MuseoSlab300','Times New Roman',serif;
}
span:after {
  content: "";
    border-bottom: 5px solid #7c61a0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Looks like wrapping caused by the `width:100%`.

Comment: note: both cases look the same in Firefox, but I do see the difference in Chrome.

Comment: are you interested in other ways to do this to avoid the problem?  or did you already fix it differently but are curious about this issue you encountered?

Comment: @andi If there is an easy solution, I'd like to hear it. Changing the markup would be a hassle at this point. Thanks.

Comment: @smilebomb I take it you want it to look like the non-whitespace case?  Here's one possibility: https://jsfiddle.net/evvrwbLw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the major difference between those two cases (with the trailing space vs. without) is that a browser will typically wrap content, if needed, at whitespace.  So in the first case (with trailing space), the browser has no choice but to push out the width of that span, because the `:after` pseudo-element can't wrap. In the second case, the browser uses the `position:absolute` declaration on the pseudo-element as a key to preserve the width of the original span, and with the whitespace there before the pseudo-element, the browser can then wrap the pseudo-element onto the next line.  You'd see this effect even if the width of the pseudo-element were set to something small like 10px instead of 100%.

Since this appears differently in Firefox vs. Chrome, I'm not sure which one is actually behaving according to standards, or if this case is even specified.

Comment: This makes sense to me. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit before I choose an answer.